# Rails ActiveRecord Associations with one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

So, I"m not sure how to setup my associations. First, I have a User model (Devise) which has email and password.

```
class User < AR::Base
end
```

After that, I have multiple types of User models which contain more details information about the users:

```
class Doctor < AR::Base
  belongs_to: User
end
```

And:

```
class Nurse < AR::Base
  belongs_to: User
end
```

And:

```
class Therapist < AR::Base
  belongs_to: User
end
```

So, I'm not sure how the User model should relate to the others. Is my design flawed?

Thanks for helping a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to implement what you are trying to achieve is to have a column on user to assign a role. So you can call the methods like this:

```
User.add_role(:doctor)
User.has_role?(:doctor)
```

You can do that using this gem https://github.com/mcrowe/roleable

Another way to implement it is by using ActiveRecord Enum:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html The implementation would look like this:

```
User.role # => :doctor
User.doctor? # => true
User.therapist! # => true
User.role # => :therapist
```

I personally prefer using enums.

A complex way to do it would be to use polymorphism. Where you can put User as a polymorphic model. This blog post explains it in great detail. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-polymorphism-to-make-a-better-activity-feed-in-rails

Comment: Thanks Paul. I eventually decided on using polymorphism and it worked great. Again, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Rails DB Associations Documentation [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

add these has_many's to user.rb

```
#user.rb
has_many :doctor 
has_many :nurse
has_many :therapist
```

and You need to add `user_id` to doctor, nurse and therapist.

Such as like:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_nurses user_id:integer
rails g migration add_user_id_to_doctors user_id:integer
rails g migration add_user_id_to_therapits user_id:integer
```

Do not forget `rake db:migrate` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to set setup a one-to-many association between these different types of users, with minimal duplicates, would be by setting up `User` to `belong_to` these other models `Doctor`, `Nurse` and `Therapist`

First, setup `has_many` association between these models to the `User` model

```
# app/models/doctor.rb
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :users
end

# app/models/nurse.rb
class Nurse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :users
end

# app/models/therapist.rb
class Therapist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :users
end
```

Then, add migrations to add `doctor_id:integer`, `nurse_id:integer` and `therapist_id:integer` to `users` table.

Then, setup `belongs_to` association to other ActiveRecord models.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :doctor
  belongs_to: :nurse
  belongs_to: :therapist
end
```

With this setup, you can access ActiveRecord data of these models as follows:

```
# get doctor associated to User.last
User.last.doctor
# get all the users who are patients of Doctor.last
Doctor.last.users

# get the nurse associated to User.last
User.last.nurse
# get all the users who are patients of Nurse.last
Nurse.last.users
```